# Vim Omnicomplete Autocomplete item selection issue

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

I am using vim with Omnicomplete. Right now when I type something I get a list of valid option as shown in the image link
[Vim Working WIth Omnicomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZbMy.png)

However as you can see none of the options are highlighted in the dropdown menu by default. I have to manually use arrow button to select an item and then press CTRL-Y to finish the selection. What I would like it to do is automatically highlight the item closely matching the word I am typing so I have to only press CTRL-Y without using the arrow keys every time if not necessary. Also how can I avoid adding a new line when pressing enter to select the item from the drop down list? Thank you.

Edit: I should mention that my drop down menu appears automatically without manually pressing CTRL-N. So what I am thinking is how can I detect that pumvisible() is active and if it is active I simulate <Down> button once. Something like

```
autocmd if pumvisible() then \<Down>
```

I don't know the exact syntax but something along this line should work? I will appreciate any advise regarding this.

Comment: "I should mention that my drop down menu appears automatically" you should have mentioned that earlier. This means that you use a plugin and that the whole completion mechanism is probably hijacked by that plugin… which makes it virtually impossible to help you. Also, `<C-n>` is not related to omnicompletion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mapping I use to obtain exactly your desired behavior:

```
inoremap ,, <C-x><C-o><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>Down>\<lt>C-p>\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it is similar to what is mentioned in [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE). However it didn't work for me. I am adding the command in .vimrc as a line. Am I doing something wrong in the way I am adding it to .vimrc. Thanks again for replying.